# How to change repeatedly the tint of an ImageView?

Tags: android, imageview

I'm working on a prototype of a Tap Game.
And I work on the animation when the player damages the monster.

The monster is only an ImageView, and I use this line to change the ImageView's tint to the color red (defined in the color.xml)

```
imageView.setColorFilter(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.damage));
```

My goal is to make the ImageView "blink" between the original ImageView and the ImageView with the red tint.
But I don't know how I can do this repeatedly.

Can you help me? (I hope I made myself clear - I'm French and my English is not very good)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest:

```
   public void blinkLimited(long started, long duration) {
   if(duration > System.currentTimeInMillis() - started) return;
   imageView.setColorFilter(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.damage));
   imageView.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ public void run() {
   imageView.setColorFilter(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.atention));
              imageView.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ public void run() {
                  blinkLimited(started, duration);
              }, 200);
   }, 200);
   }
```

Execute blinkLimited(System.currentTimeInMillis(), 2000) and you notice.

Comment: Hello, first thank you for your answer, Its work !

but uuuh how i can make its stop if i want make the animation last during just 2 seconds? Like you say its forever ^^'

Comment: Check answer, 2000 is in ms equals two seconds, if the answer helped upvote, if it solves please accept as correct

Comment: What is `elapsed`? @MarcosVasconcelos

Comment: Should be duration